# Quote similar to "the pen is mightier than the sword"

Tags: quotes, popular-refrains, proverbs

I'm looking for a quote that is similar to "the pen is mightier than the sword", which is commonly credited to Edward George Bulwer-Lytton. The quote should state the same thing, namely, that words are very powerful, and in the best case be attributable to some author / historic figure. Thanks for any ideas or thoughts.

Comment: https://www.age-of-the-sage.org/quotations/quotes/the_pen_is_mightier_than_the_sword.html

Comment: How is this not purely about vocabulary and writing style, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Words cut deeper than a knife.**

Originally by [William Chapman](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/994623-words-cut-deeper-than-knives-a-knife-can-be-pulled) (Author):

> “Words cut deeper than knives. A knife can be pulled out, words are
>   embedded into our souls.”

Popularised recently by [Sean Mendes (video with lyrics)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jIX0HymVmGE).

Comment: Thanks, but isn't your quote rather saying that it is better to meet and talk than to go to war? Because that's not emphasizing the power of the word but rather the ugliness of war.

Comment: @JanKleinow I've edited the answer to make more sense.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I do not know why and by who this whole thread was downvoted.

Comment: @JanKleinow Nor do I, it's not unknown for random anonymous drive-by voting or sock-puppet tactical voting to happen. The system is pretty good at catching serial occurances and reversing  the effects - if that's what happened.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this:

> The power of words is immense. A well-chosen word has often sufficed to stop a flying army, to change defeat into victory and to save an empire.

Emile de Girardin